# Redirect Outgoing VPN server traffic running in a container to another container port

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, docker, linux-networking

A docker container hosting a VPN server needs it outgoing traffic (presumably the internet traffic) to be sent to another container which would send it to the internet.

Following is the idea,

> Container A(VPN Server) -> Container B (Specific port) -> Internet

I have tried a couple of things with iptables but was unable to resolve this.

Things I tried

Hosted a redsocks server in Container A along with the VPN.

Container A `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345`

I have also tried the following,

> Container A(VPN Server) -> Container B (Redsocks) -> Container C
>   (Specific port)-> Internet

Please let me know if this is possible or there is an alternative.